# ¿Cómo corregir este error al consumir mi API en un front?

Tags: python, reactjs

Buen dia,
Realize una api en Python, la ejecuto normal y me muestra en chorme la informacion en formato JSON hasta ahi bien, pero realize un front en react usando dom y axios para consumir la api y cuando la corro miro la consola y me salen los siguientes errores:

Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://127.0.0.1:4000/sebastian (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Código de estado: 200.

y

```
Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { message: "Request failed with status code 404", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, response: {…}, stack: "" }
funciones.js:7
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradezco la ayuda.

No se si hay otra forma de consumir la misma api en un fornt (asi sea en otro lenguaje) si me puden ayudar o que me recomiendan?

API DE PYTHON:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


from sebas import sebastian

@app.route('/sebastian') 
def getSebastian():
    return jsonify(sebastian)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, port = 4000)


sebastian = [
    {
    "1Nombre":"xd",
    "2Apellido":"xd",
    "3Telefono":"xd",
    "4Cedula":"xd",
    "5Edad":1   
    }

]
```

CODIGO DE REACT:

```
--- app.js
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Inicio from './components/Inicio'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="contenedor">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Inicio></Inicio>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
---- funciones.js
import axios from "axios";


const sebastian = async () => {
    const  peticion = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:4000/sebastian')
    console.log(peticion.sebastian)
}
export {
    sebastian
}
---- inicio.jsx
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

import { sebastian } from "../functions/funciones";

const Inicio = () =>{

    useEffect(()=>{
        sebastian()
    },[])

    return (
        <div>Inicio</div>
    )
}

export default Inicio
----
```

Comment: Código en formato código por favor, sino tenemos que copiarlo todo a mano y... nadie lo va a hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás haciendo una llamada al puerto 4000 de Python des de la app de React, que normalmente se ejecuta des del 3000, por lo que al haber un cambio de puerto es un cambio de origen y la CORS bloquea la petición.

La solución para el desarrollo es usar el proxy:

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dealing-with-cors-in-create-react-app